# Pass json data from one component to an other. Vue.js

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying all day to figure out how to pass data from one component to another. I have read a lot of relevant tutorials and instructions, unfortunately with out luck.

I have fetched some data from an api and i present them in the home.vue
and i want to pass the data into a new file to generate a page that will show a random product from the list.

Maybe the approach is totally wrong, but it is the first time that i use vue components, i have experience just with the instance

I'm trying to implement it using props to return the data to the new page.

Here is the randomize.vue file where I would like to pass my data

```js
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <p> {{ this.propsdata[0].e }} </p>
  <h1>dla;dl;djal;d</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "randomize",
  props: ["propsdata"],
  data() {
    return {
        obj: this.propsdata
    };
  },
  mounted(){
   console.log(this.props);
  },
};
</script>
```

This is the home.vue file that i fetch the data

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div class=" main-conte" >
                 <randomize  :propsData=toBeShown />

<transition-group name="fade" tag="div" id="container"  class=" row "  >
      <figure v-for="(value,index) in  toBeShownOrdered" id="page-wrap" :key="index" class="beer-container col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-2"   >
         <a  >
    <img @click="goTodetail(value.id)" class="logo lazy img-responsive loaded" v-bind:src="getMissingImg(index)"/>
          <figcaption>
            <div class="beer-title">{{value.name}}</div>
            <div class="beer-availability"> {{value.tagline}}</div>
            <div class="learn-more">
              <h4 class="beer-info-title">Format</h4>
              <span class="serving-icons"></span>
              <div class="serving">
             <i v-if="value.abv >= 0 && value.abv <=6 " class="fas fa-wine-glass-alt"></i> 
             <i v-if="value.abv >= 6 && value.abv <=7" class="fas fa-glass-cheers"></i>
             <i v-if="value.abv >= 7 && value.abv <=100" class="fas fa-wine-bottle"></i>
             <span class="measure">{{value.abv}}</span>%</div>
             </div>
           </figcaption>
           </a>
     </figure>
     </transition-group>
<div class=prev-next>
<button @click="orderByName = !orderByName">Click Me!</button>

<button class="prev" @click="prevPage" :disabled="currentPage==1">
<i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i></button>
      <button class="next"  @click="nextPage" :disabled="currentPage == totalPages">
<i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>     </button>
</div>
</div>
  <div>
  </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mdbView, mdbMask } from "mdbvue";
import FadeTransition from "./fade-transition.vue";

import randomize from "@/components/randomize";



export default {
  name: "home",

  components: {
    mdbView,
    mdbMask,
    FadeTransition,
    randomize
  },

  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
       message: '',
      currentPage: 1,
      orderByName: false,


 };
  },
  computed: {
    //show more less products
   toBeShown() {
      return this.items.slice(0, this.currentPage * 5);

    },
    totalPages() {
      return Math.ceil( this.items.length / 4);
    },
    toBeShownOrdered() {
  return this.orderByName ? _.orderBy(this.toBeShown, 'name', 'asc') : this.toBeShown;
}
 },

  mounted() {
    this.fetchData();

    
  },
  


  methods: {
    fetchData: function() {
      const myRequest = new Request("https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers");
      fetch(myRequest)
        .then(response => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
          this.items = data;

          console.log(this.items);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
    getMissingImg(index) {
      return this.images[index];
    },

    nextPage(){
      if(this.currentPage <  this.totalPages) this.currentPage++;
    },
    prevPage(){
      this.currentPage = this.currentPage - 1 || 1;
    },
      goTodetail(prodId) {
    let proId=prodId
    this.$router.push({name:'blog',params:{Pid:proId}})
    
      },
```

index.js

```html
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import home from '@/components/home'
import blog from '@/components/blog'
import randomize from '@/components/randomize'



Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: home,
      props:true
    },
    {
      path: '/blog/:Pid',
      name: 'blog',
      component: blog,
      props:true

    },
    {
      path: '/randomize/',
      name: 'randomize',
      component: randomize,
      props:true

    },
  ]
})
```

Comment: make it as `<randomize  :propsData=toBeShown ></randomize>`

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, unfortunately no luck i get this error .           [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: Props have to be passed in kebab-case. Then, if i understand you load data from Page 1, and display them on page 2, am i right ?

Comment: Can you do <p> {{ JSON.stringify(this.propsdata) }} </p> to see what is in `this.propsData`. 
Also give quotes here
`<randomize :propsData="toBeShown" ></randomize>`

Comment: @AdrienRosi no i want to pass data from the page2 to page 1....

Comment: @Helpinghand Unfortunately i cannot see anything...

Answer (score 1):

You would benefit from using [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) as it will keep your state at the application level (as opposed to component *data* which keeps each component state at the component level).

Setting up vuex requires a bit more work and has a learning curve, but unless you won't grow your app to a medium/large size it will in the long term benefit you by decreasing the overall complexity of your app.

In short, all components from your app can access the state stored in vuex without having to deal with props. And from any component, you can *dispatch actions* implemented in your vuex store to alter the vuex state. Vuex will help keeping your components focused on presenting data and capturing user actions.

To ease setting up a Vue app with vue-router and vuex, you could choose to build your app with [nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/guide) which is a framework that provides you with vue+vue-router+vuex with no effort. Nuxt.js will also help setting up server side rendering which would be beneficial to SEO if your app is to be indexed by search engines.

Comment: I made some modification i can see my data finally but there is a weird behaviour. I print the data in randomize.vue but while i am clicking on this page is empty and the vue print my data in the first page instead of randomize.vue